# JSONP Callback is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm a NOOB and I see that other users have encountered a similar problem, but after many hours of frustration, I cannot get a JSONP callback function to work.

I'm trying to extract the "woeid" information from Yahoo geo.places so I can use it to specify the location to obtain weather data.  I receive input (such as a zip code) from the "location" id in a form and submit it to Yahoo.

The code is returning an XMLHttpRequest object, which I can read by looking at xhr.responseText in the console, but I can't extract the JSON object that is being passed to the callback function by the server.

I know I must be making a simple error, however I can't figure out what it is.  I'm trying to do this through Javascript prior to learning how to retrieve the data using the $.ajax method in jQuery.

Can you tell me where the error is?  Here is my code:

```
// an XMLTHttpRequest
var xhr = null;

/*
* void
* getWoeid()
* gets WOEID from Yahoo geo.places to use in request
* for weather data
*
*/



function getWoeid() {
// instantiate XMLHttpRequest object
try {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// handle old browsers
if (xhr == null) {
    alert("Ajax not supported by your browser!");
    return;
}

// construct URL
var userinput = document.getElementById("location").value;

var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from" +
            " geo.places where text =" + userinput);

var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + data + "&format=json&    callback=callback";


// get data
xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send(null);
}


// callback function
function callback(response) {
    woeid = response;
}


/*
* void
* handler()
*
* Handles the Ajax response
*/

function handler() {

// only handle loaded requests
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

    // display response if possible
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
          var location = woeid;
    }

    else    
       alert("Error with Ajax call");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an XHR object to request a JSONP result, because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Also, even if you would make a request locally, using an XHR object to make the request would mean that the `callback` function would not be called, you would just get the code for calling it in the response.

To get make a JSONP request, you use a script tag:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your explanation was tremendously helpful.  I've eliminated the use of the XHR object, and using the additional code you provided, I'm now able to access the variable defined in the callback function.